# redirect to "servlet?success"

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Inside a doPost method of my servlet, I'm creating a person. When I have successfully created a person, how can I redirect from

```
http://localhost:8080/site/register
```

to

```
http://localhost:8080/site/register?success
```

Comment: See [Forward versus redirect](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=181).

Comment: I understand that, but how do I assign `?success` part to servlet ?

Comment: If you want to use a forward instead then you can put the additional data in the session or request before forwarding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a redirect message to the client from a servlet you can use the built in method of the response object.

```
    response.sendRedirect("/register?success");
```

Comment: I get exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed` when I write `response.sendRedirect("/" + request.getServletPath() + "?success");` why ?

Comment: If you have written data to the response previously then you will get this exception. You need to design your logic so that your servlet does not write anything until you decide if you need to redirect or otherwise.

Comment: In any case you should not be writing to the client in a servlet, just do the logic then forward to a JSP or other view technology to display info to the client.

Comment: Ok thanks, should I remove this topic or Accept your answer :) ?

Comment: Up to you. If the question is valid and you got an answer that helped then leave it so others may benefit.